# Why is anyhow not working in the stable version?

Tags: rust, anyhow

I have a clean project to which I include anyhow 1.0.66.
Installed the latest version of rust.
I'm getting an error saying that anyhow requires a nightly version. Perhaps this is due to the use of backtrace, but it is supported in rust version 1.65. I don't understand how to solve the problem.

> Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "libfs"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[dependencies]
tokio = {version = "1.22", features = ["full"]}
anyhow = {version = "1.0.66", features = ["default"]}
```

> src/lib.rs

```rust
#[tokio::test]
async fn run_test() {
    println!("test");
}
```

> output

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.66
error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> /home/dima/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anyhow-1.0.66/src/lib.rs:214:32
    |
214 | #![cfg_attr(backtrace, feature(error_generic_member_access, provide_any))]
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0554]: `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel
   --> /home/dima/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anyhow-1.0.66/src/lib.rs:214:61
    |
214 | #![cfg_attr(backtrace, feature(error_generic_member_access, provide_any))]
    |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0554`.
error: could not compile `anyhow` due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Some backtrace APIs are now stabilized in the standard library as of 1.65, yes. That does not mean that `anyhow`'s backtrace feature no longer require nightly. The now-stable APIs may not be sufficient for `anyhow`'s backtrace feature. I recommend following this issue: https://github.com/dtolnay/anyhow/issues/284

Answer (score 15):

The problem was solved by:

```
rm -rf target
cargo check
```

This seems to be related to [dtolnay/anyhow/issues/250](https://github.com/dtolnay/anyhow/issues/250) and [rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/12973](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/12973).